# Fill Model Class With query results

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, linq-to-sql

I Have the Following Model
ProductDetails.cs

```
public class ProductDetails
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public string ProductCodeID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public List<ProductDetails> lstProductDetails { get; set; }

}
```

Need to fill this model class with the query results that I'm getting from the DB

This is what I tried ..

```
    var results = from a in db.ProductInfoes where productCodeID.Equals(productCodeID)
                    select new ProductDetails
                    {
                        ProductName = a.Product_Name.ToString(),
                        ProductCategoryID= a.Category_ID.ToString(),
                        ProductDescription = a.Product_Description.ToString()
                    };
```

What's the best way to update model class with query results?

Comment: Why do you want `List<ProductDetails>` inside `ProductDetails`? Can we move out to different model

Comment: You have a circular reference with ProductDetails.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar - I got two situations, one i want to get full table data, In order to retrieve full table data I use this List<ProductDetails>
 and other situation is to retrieve one record from the table. - Any idea how to fill Model Class With query results?

Answer (score 0):

you can try extending ProductInfoes and using automapper.

```
public **partial class** ProductInfoes {
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<AuthorModel, AuthorDTO>();
        });
IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();

        public ProductDetails Map()
        {
            return iMapper.Map<ProductInfoes , ProductDetails>(this);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `lstProductDetails` property from the `ProductDetails` class.

to get all data (results will be of type: `List<ProductDetails>`)

```
var results = db.ProductInfoes
                   .Select(x => new ProductDetails()
                    {
                        ProductName = x.Product_Name.ToString(),
                        ProductCategoryID= x.Category_ID.ToString(),
                        ProductDescription = x.Product_Description.ToString()
                    }).ToList();
```

to get one record (result will be of type: `ProductDetails`):

```
var result = db.ProductInfoes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.productCodeID.Equals(productCodeID))
                   .Select(x => new ProductDetails()
                    {
                        ProductName = x.Product_Name.ToString(),
                        ProductCategoryID= x.Category_ID.ToString(),
                        ProductDescription = x.Product_Description.ToString()
                    };
```

(Add namespace System.Linq)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Matt.G with this way I'm still getting empty model.
how do I add this list results into ProductDetails model?

Comment: public ProductDetails getSelectedProductDetails(string ID)
{
   NaturesKingdomUKEntities db = new NaturesKingdomUKEntities();
   
   List<ProductInfo> lst_Info = db.ProductInfoes.ToList();
   
   ProductDetails prd = new ProductDetails();
   
   List<ProductDetails> lst_ProductDetails = lst_Info
            .Where(y => y.Product_Code_ID.Equals(ID))
            .Select(x => new ProductDetails {ProductName=x.Product_Name, ID=x.Product_Code_ID })
            .ToList();
   return prd;   //still empty model  :(              
}

Comment: verify if ProductInfo table in db has data in it. if yes, its possible that there is some incorrect/missing configuration in the db context

Comment: Yes. [ProductInfo] has data (two records)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ProductDetails getSelectedProductDetails(string productCodeID)
    {
        try
        {
            NaturesKingdomUKEntities db = new NaturesKingdomUKEntities();

            List<ProductInfo> lst_ProductInfo = db.ProductInfoes.Where(x => x.Product_Code_ID.Equals(productCodeID)).ToList();

            ProductDetails prd = new ProductDetails();                    

            prd = lst_ProductInfo
                                 .Where(y => y.Product_Code_ID.Equals(productCodeID))
                                 .Select(x => new ProductDetails { ProductName = x.Product_Name, ProductCodeID = x.Product_Code_ID, UnitPrice=Convert.ToDouble(x.Unit_Price), ProductDescription=x.Product_Description, ProductAdditionalDescription=x.Product_Additional_Description, ProductType=x.Product_Type })
                                 .FirstOrDefault();                
            return prd;                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Finally it works with this way. Thanks a lot guys @Matt.G